# non-root users can run passwd command as root, why can't they change password of root?

Tags: setuid, passwd

I know about `setuid` bit on `/bin/passwd` file which allows us (non-root user) to run that command as `root` user. running `passwd` command requires `root` permissions to change `/etc/shadow` file.

My question is if I am running `passwd` command as `root` why I can't change the password of `root` since I am `root` while I am running that command?

```
edward@ArchLinux:~$ passwd root
passwd: You may not view or modify password information for root.
```

Is it `passwd` command that does not allows non-root user to change the password? Can I write a malicious `passwd` command with setuid bit that can change any user's password?

(*Logically I know that this would be disastrous but I want to know how this works in background*)

Comment: @muru it is because `passwd` command is made not to allow non-root user to change password of other users? can I modify passwd command with setuid to change password of root?

Comment: If you can modify `passwd`, you can get it to do anything, right?

Comment: @muru that is what I am asking

Comment: Simply writing to a setuid file doesn't remove the setuid bit (assuming you can write to it).

Comment: Do you have root privileges to write to `passwd`? If so, why would you need to write `passwd` to do "malicious" stuff?

Comment: @muru that is not what I meant

Comment: What did you mean? To write a setuid root program, you need to have root privileges. And if you do have them, why go through a setuid root program?

Comment: @muru the point was how can setuid be exploited if not used carefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`passwd(1)` checks the credentials of whoever invokes it, and if that isn't `root` it doesn't allow to change the relevant entries for other users.

The scenario you describe is exactly the reason why SUID/SGID programs have to be written with the utmost care, to avoid the possibility of them being tricked into doing something unexpected, or compromised in some way.

Comment: but I can write a malicious `passwd` command and let non-root user change anyone's password right?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds yes, but to do that you need to already have root access so the point is moot. If you have root access you can do pretty much anything anyway.

Comment: @terdon I am well aware of that sir, but the point was how can setuid be exploited if not used carefully

Comment: @edwardtorvalds OK,  but that's not a valid example of it. And it's also not what your question was about. Sure, you can create a malicious _anything_ if you have root access and then make it SUID. However, doing so requires root access so the danger is not so much in allowing SUID programs but in permitting users to obtain root access.